# How to use Buffer.from() with crypto.timingSafeEqual()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

For some reason I get

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined
```

from both arguments to `crypto.timingSafeEqual(a, b)`.

I have also tried

```
const a = Buffer.from(signature, 'utf8').toString('base64');
const b = Buffer.from(expectedSignature, 'utf8').toString('base64');
```

and I get the same error.

**Question**

Can anyone figure out why the arguments aren't Buffers?

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const secret = "x";

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

function isSigOk(request, secret) {
    // calculate the signature
    const expectedSignature = "sha256=" +
        crypto.createHmac("sha256", secret)
            .update(JSON.stringify(request.body))
            .digest("hex");

    // compare the signature against the one in the request
    const signature = request.headers["X-Hub-Signature-256"];
    const a = Buffer.from(signature);
    const b = Buffer.from(expectedSignature);
    return crypto.timingSafeEqual(a, b);
};

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  if (isSigOk(req, secret)) {
    // Do stuff here
  } else {
    console.log('Error: Signatures does not match. Return res.status(401)');
  };
  res.status(200).end();
});

// Start express on the defined port
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Github wekhook listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: I don't think the error is from `timingSafeEqual`, I think it's from `Buffer.from`. (You get exactly the same error if you do `Buffer.from(undefined)`.) That tells me that `request.headers["X-Hub-Signature-256"]` is `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder When I `console.log` this `const signature = request.headers["x-hub-signature-256"];` I get `sha256=01df1ffc00107ab2e8782ba7983bb7245df79b6b414d4e89f8357144d61613cb`, so I get data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. The first and main one is that `isSigOk` assumes there **will** be a value for the `"X-Hub-Signature-256"` header:

   ```
   const signature = request.headers["X-Hub-Signature-256"];
   const a = Buffer.from(signature);
   ```

   That `Buffer.from` call will throw the error you've quoted if `signature` is `undefined` because the header isn't there. You probably want to return `false` in that case (and probably skip the overhead of working out the expected signature by reordering things a bit), see `***` comments and associated lines:

   ```
   function isSigOk(request, secret) {
       // *** get the signature on this message, if any
       const signature = request.headers["X-Hub-Signature-256"];
       if (!signature) {
           // *** none
           return false;
       }
       // calculate the signature
       const expectedSignature = "sha256=" +
           crypto.createHmac("sha256", secret)
               .update(JSON.stringify(request.body))
               .digest("hex");

       // compare the signature against the one in the request
       const a = Buffer.from(signature);
       const b = Buffer.from(expectedSignature);
       return crypto.timingSafeEqual(a, b);
   };
   ```
2. Capitalization matters. According to the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers) (Express's `Request` object inherits from Node.js's `IncomingMessage`), `headers`'s names are lowercased. So `request.headers["X-Hub-Signature-256"]` should be `request.headers["x-hub-signature-256"]`. (In a comment you've saying you were getting a value, but the comment used all lowercase, whereas the code uses mixed case.) So:

   ```
   function isSigOk(request, secret) {
       // *** get the signature on this message, if any
       const signature = request.headers["x-hub-signature-256"]; // *** Lowercase
       if (!signature) {
           // *** none
           return false;
       }
       // calculate the signature
       const expectedSignature = "sha256=" +
           crypto.createHmac("sha256", secret)
               .update(JSON.stringify(request.body))
               .digest("hex");

       // compare the signature against the one in the request
       const a = Buffer.from(signature);
       const b = Buffer.from(expectedSignature);
       return a.length === b.length && crypto.timingSafeEqual(a, b);
   };
   ```

   Note the `a.length === b.length &&` part of that. [`timingSafeEqual`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptotimingsafeequala-b) will throw an error if the buffers aren't the same length, but we wan to return false in that situation instead.

Comment: Better compare the byteLength in the return like  `return Buffer.byteLength(a) === Buffer.byteLength(b) && crypto.timingSafeEqual(a, b);`
, otherwise it may throw `RangeError` in nodejs if two buffs have the different length.

Comment: @ikhvjs - Good catch, thanks! I'm surprised it doesn't just return `false` in that case, but the docs bear out what you said: it throws an error. :-)

Comment: Thank you - this is a very clear answer and great code.